# Returning to the app after paypal payment

Tags: angularjs, paypal, ionic-framework, returnurl

I need paypal payment gateway for my app. I want to open an in app browser after checkout which open paypal site, do the transactions and after success return be back to my app. How should I implement this using Angularjs.

Is there any build-in plugins available?

Answer (score 0):

[PayPal-Cordova-Plugin](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Cordova-Plugin) is the way to go. Build and check this [sample app](https://github.com/romk1n/MyCordovaShop).

For the [sample app](https://github.com/romk1n/MyCordovaShop), follow these instructions:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/romk1n/MyCordovaShop.git
$ cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-console
$ cordova plugin add com.paypal.cordova.mobilesdk
$ cordova platform add android   
$ cordova run android
```

Comment: how to post the order to the paypal website from the app and then return to the app?

Comment: I found a better way , and updated the answer. @abc3018. Please try it.